# Jsonpath querying only one item

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a problem to find out only a determined value in a json using jsonpath.
I have this json:

```
{"tvs": {
    {  "tv": [
    {
      "serial": "HD1300",
      "data": [
        {
          "title": "manufacturer",
          "value": "lg"
        },
        {
          "title": "color",
          "value": "silver"
        },
        {
          "title": "inches",
          "value": 32
        },
        {
          "title": "connection",
          "value": 220
        },

        {
          "title": "connection",
          "value": 400
        }
    ]

    }.. more tvs
```

And I want to know if the value connection:400 is present for serial hd1300
I already tried with:

```
$.tvs.[?(@.serial=='hd1340')].data.[?(@.title== 'connection'),(@.value==400)]
```

But my problem is that I retrieve also the "connection" with 200. How can I filter to get only this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have an error in your JSON (extra brace between tvs and tv). I was able to get this to work on http://jsonpath.com.

```
{"tvs": 
    {  "tv": [
    {
      "serial": "HD1300",
      "data": [
        {
          "title": "manufacturer",
          "value": "lg"
        },
        {
          "title": "color",
          "value": "silver"
        },
        {
          "title": "inches",
          "value": 32
        },
        {
          "title": "connection",
          "value": 220
        },
        {
          "title": "connection",
          "value": 400
        }
        ]}
    ]}
}
```

$.tvs.tv.[?(@.serial=='HD1300')].data.[?(@.title=='connection' && @.value=='400')]

Comment: The json has an error but it was non intended (It is another json the importan) but thanks for the "&&" hint with that is working. Thanks